# SVG patternTransform scale image without translating

Tags: javascript, svg

I know there are several questions on here about scaling an `<image>` and sorts on the centre of said element but I have a slightly different problem.

My problem being I have a `<pattern>` which contains my `<image>` as it is applied dynamically to other SVGs. I'm using the `patternTransform` attribute to scale and translate the image with a matrix (rather than individual transforms). I need to scale the image around the centre of the image although my understanding is that `<pattern>` is an infinite canvas of it's contents.

I have tried the technique outlined [here (Transforming Coordinate system)](http://commons.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/SVG_Essentials/Transforming_the_Coordinate_System#Technique:_Scaling_Around_a_Center_Point)

**summary of the link**
X = centreX * (scale_factor -1)
Y = centreY * (scale_factor -1)

It has certainly made a difference to the way the image appears to translate but the origin looks more like it is about 15% from the top/left as opposed to the centre of the proverbial `<image>`.

How do I scale the image without translating it while the image resides within a `<pattern>` and used as a `fill`?

Below is the code I'm using to scale the image and a gif of how it's behaving.

**pattern definition**

```
<pattern id="user_image_container" patternUnits="objectBoundingBox" x="0" y="0">
  <image xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8a/Free_Unedited_Happy_Little_Yellow_Stars_in_Pink_Flower_Creative_Commons_(2898759838).jpg" id="user_image"></image>
</pattern>
```

**Javascript controlling the matrix**

```
/**
 * Scale the image. Called by an input event from an input[type="range"]
 * @param  {Event} event calling this function.
 * @return {void}
 */
update_image_scale: function update_image_scale(event) {
  // Stop anything automatic from happening.
  event.preventDefault()

  // Get the input and previous value.
  const target_input = $(event.target)
  const target_size = parseFloat(target_input.val())
  const image_size = App.canvas_view.image_size // Original size of the image.

  // Get the target <pattern>.
  const target_image = $("#user_image_container").get(0)

  // Get the centred X/Y position of the image.
  const cx = parseFloat(target_image.getAttribute("data-x") || 0) + (image_size.width / 2)
  const cy = parseFloat(target_image.getAttribute("data-y") || 0) + (image_size.height / 2)

  // Get the new translation position.
  const x = -cx * (target_size - 1)
  const y = -cy * (target_size - 1)

  console.log(x, y)

  // Set the new X/Y position.
  target_image.setAttribute("data-x", x)
  target_image.setAttribute("data-y", y)

  // Redraw the image.
  $("#user_image_container").get(0).setAttribute("patternTransform", `matrix(${target_size} 0 0 ${target_size} ${x} ${y})`)
},
```

Here's how it behaves at the moment (sorry for the large gif):
  This is controlled with an `input[type="range"]` `input` event, it starts to get wild as the scale goes > 2.
[image: Oddity]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After leaving this alone for a few days, I finally sussed it.

The way to centre an `<image>` in a `<pattern>` is to not try and (logically) use the `<image>` to base the `translate` on but in-fact use the `<pattern>` to base the `translate` on.

I.E

```
  /**
   * Scale the image.
   * @param  {Event} event calling this function.
   * @return {void}
   */
  update_image_scale: function update_image_scale(event) {
    // Stop anything automatic from happening.
    event.preventDefault()

    // Get the mask dimensions.
    const mask_container_size = $("#image_mask").get(0).getBBox()

    // Get the target image.
    const target_image = $("#user_image_container").get(0)

    // Get the input and previous value.
    const target_size = parseFloat($(event.target).val())

    // Get the new translation position.
    const x = (-mask_container_size.width / 2) * (target_size - 1)
    const y = (-mask_container_size.height / 2) * (target_size - 1)

    // Set the new X/Y position.
    target_image.setAttribute("data-scale-x", x)
    target_image.setAttribute("data-scale-y", y)

    // Redraw the image.
    global.App.canvas_view.render_image_in_pattern()
  }
```

And the matrix controller is now individual transforms.

```
  /**
   * Render the image with all transforms.
   * @return {void}
   */
  render_image_in_pattern: function render_image_in_pattern() {
    // Get the target image.
    const target = this.$("#user_image_container").get(0)

    // Get the image coordinates.
    const sx = parseFloat(target.getAttribute("data-scale-x")) || 0
    const sy = parseFloat(target.getAttribute("data-scale-y")) || 0
    const x = parseFloat(target.getAttribute("data-x")) || 0
    const y = parseFloat(target.getAttribute("data-y")) || 0

    // Get the rotation.
    const r = this.rotation || 0

    // Get the scale from the range field.
    const s = $(".image-scaler").val()

    // Translate the image.
    $("#user_image_container").get(0)
      .setAttribute("patternTransform", `translate(${sx} ${sy}) rotate(${r}) scale(${s}) translate(${x} ${y})`)
  },
```

The `data-x` and `data-y` attributes are set by another function for drag and drop purposes.